# Does the Power Rangers' strict use of proportional power derive from a specific principle or mandate?

Tags: power-rangers

In all (or nearly all) of the incarnations of the Power Rangers, the Rangers follow an apparently strict protocol on only responding to threats with proportional power. They typically start fighting hand-to-hand in their street clothes, "Suiting Up" only after they start to lose. Later, the Zords and (finally) the MegaZord only come out when it is plainly evident that the Rangers will lose without them.

Has this practice been officially commented upon in-universe in any clear way? To be clear, a similar prohibition on the use of excessive force is a part of many real-world law enforcement agencies and is typically part of modern law enforcement officer training (e.g. US cops, despite nearly all carrying firearms, are trained not to draw their weapon unless they have no other reasonable choice).

Why don't the Rangers ever use "excessive" force, such as immediately calling down their MegaZord to crush the enemy robots, demon ninjas, space princesses, or other villains du jour before they have a chance to adapt rather than engaging them in an "honorable" extended battle? Is there ever a mention that a *specific* code of conduct on the use of proportional force is imposed upon or accepted by the Rangers, or is a purely out-of-universe "get past the censors" or "make a story lasting more than ten seconds" rationale the controlling factor?

Comment: [Reddit: How come the Power Rangers don't go straight to their Zords when the monster of the week appears?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/2879ra/power_rangers_how_come_the_power_rangers_dont_go/)